# Display WordPress categories for Custom Post Types (specifically for that post) in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm using a Javascript filter which shows and hide a list (loop) of Custom Post Types based on their category.

I'm trying to add the category slug as a class. But I only want to display the categories that are assigned to a specific loop item. Each item can have multiple categories.

I've done it this way, but it dumps all the categories on each loop, not ones specifically for that loop item.

```
<?php
    $pageID = get_the_ID();
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'casestudies', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    $taxonomy = 'custom_casestudies';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<div class="block-wrap mix <?php foreach ($terms as $term) echo  ' ' . $term->slug; ?>">
    // loop content
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_terms returns all of the terms in the given taxonomy. In this case you should be using wp_get_post_terms, which returns a list of terms for a given post. The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) goes into more detail.

Comment: I've tried that, even `$terms = wp_get_post_terms($pageID, 'custom_casestudies');` but nothing is displaying. The docs mention `$post-ID` but where do I get that ID from?

Comment: I've also tried `$terms = wp_get_post_terms($loop->id, 'custom_casestudies');` which also doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding ```global $post;``` before your WP_Query. That should allow you to access ```$post->ID```.

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, I'm still not getting any further. I can now see the `$post->ID` and updated to this `$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custom_casestudies');` but still not displaying anything.

Comment: What is ```wp_get_post_terms``` returning?

Comment: a `var_dump($terms)` produces `array (size=0) empty` on each loop item

Comment: Think I have it - Needed to add it after the `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else and thanks to Matt (who answered) this is working.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'casestudies', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custom_casestudies');
?>
<div class="block-wrap mix<?php foreach ($terms as $term) echo  ' ' . $term->slug ?>">
    // content
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The terms have been to be after the `while` loop.